# Date with Timezone in Java

Tags: java

What is the Simple Date Format for "2014-01-02T23:03:30-05:00"?

I have googled and got the format only, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz. But this format is only working when my date format is without colon in the end "2014-01-02T23:03:30-0500".

Can anyone please advise on this?

Comment: use ss'Z' instead of ssz

Comment: I don't think that `Z` will accept a colon either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the letter `X` for `ISO 8601 timezone`.

```java
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TimeZoneTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException {

        final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
        final String string = "2014-01-02T23:03:30-05:00";
        final Date date = format.parse(string);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for quick response.  Can you help on this please, 
Date= 2014-01-02T23:03:30-05:00 by using this format 
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX , i got answer as 2014-01-03T09:33:30+05, can you explain this please?

Answer (score 6):

If you use Java 7, you can replace the `z` by a `X` to allow for colon separator: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX`.

See also the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Before Java 7, you need to either parse it manually by first removing the colon or you can use an external library such as Jodatime or threeten.

Comment: Hi @assylias thanks for the swift response. I got the answer by using X in jdk1.6 itself. Thanks . another help need, 
2014-01-02T23:03:30-05:00 by using this format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX i got answer as 2014-01-03T09:33:30+05, can you explain this please?

Comment: I didn't know that X worked with jdk6. I'm not sure I understand your question. If you print the result then it will be in your timezone so if you are in GMT+5 will be offset from -05:00 to +05:00, which is 10 hours ahead of the original time.

Comment: Hi @assylias, thanks once again, can you please give one example for me.? i can not able to get your point. please?

Comment: `2014-01-02T23:03:30-05:00` and `2014-01-03T09:03:30+05:00` represent the same instant in time, in two different time zones.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `X` instead of the `Z`

[docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can pass that string directly to a constructor in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3. No need for a formatter. Joda-Time uses that standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format as its default, even tolerating the lack of a colon in the offset.

Instead of passing `DateTimeZone.UTC` as I did in my example code below, you would pass the specific time zone of your interest.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

String string = "2014-01-02T23:03:30-0500";
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( string, DateTimeZone.UTC );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
```

When run:

```
dateTime: 2014-01-03T04:03:30.000Z
```